# How to use DAY/WEEK/MONTH/YEAR constant as parameter in stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, procedure-definition

Assume I have a table looks like this:

```
Scores {
    Id uniqueidentifier,
    ScoredAt datetime,
    Value int
}
```

Basically I want to create a stored procedure that works similar to this DATEDIFF(DAY, @day, GETDATE()) which can use DAY/WEEK... as parameter. This is what i did:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetHighScores
    @scope int --- <<== THIS GUY HERE
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM Honor.Scores
    WHERE DATEDIFF(@scope, Honor.Scores.ScoredAt, GETDATE()) = 0
END
GO
```

What do I have to put into GetHighScores parameter so that I can do this:

```
EXEC GetHighScores(MONTH)
```

As far as I know, MONTH/WEEK/DAY.. those are not actually a value but more of a tricky macro. But that guy DATEDIFF can use it, why couldn't I?

Anyone have any idea to get this done?

Comment: @Ngoc  Are are getting the error "Invalid parameter 1 specified for datediff"  ?    You are passing an INT variable into the DATEDIFF function as its first parameter. It expects the format DATEADD (datepart , number , date )... i.e.   not an integer but dd for days or mm for months etc..

Comment: (1) you'll need to use dynamic SQL or separate objects or separate queries or pre-calculate a cutoff, because DATEDIFF() doesn't take variables or expressions for the first argument, only constants. (2) Your where clause completely destroys sargability - even if the query could be satisfied by an index, your application of a function against the column is going to force a full scan. (3) How are you passing the word `MONTH` into `@scope`, which is an `INT`? (4) What version of SQL Server please?

Comment: @DamagedGoods but even if the parameter were a string, you still can't put a variable into the first argument for DATEADD.

Comment: @aaron  Yep, I was working backwards from inside out his original procedure, posted just that to push Ngoc down the right path

Comment: @Ngoc I voted your question back up the scale as obviously your new to the forum and you did bother to come back and format the question after original comments.  Please vote aaron's complete answer up when you have enough rep as mine was not a ideal solution, but hopefully pushed you in the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumes that your week starts on a Sunday, and that you only have data from the past. If you need to collect data for this week/month/year/today and exclude data from the future, you need to calculate a start and end range instead of a single cutoff.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetHighScores -- always use schema prefix!
  @scope VARCHAR(5) -- why an int?
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON; -- always use this!

  DECLARE @d DATETIME, @cutoff DATETIME;
  SET @d = DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE());

  SET @cutoff = DATEADD(DAY, 1-CASE UPPER (@scope) 
    WHEN 'MONTH' THEN DAY(@d)
    WHEN 'WEEK'  THEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @d)
    WHEN 'YEAR'  THEN DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, @d)
    WHEN 'DAY'   THEN 1 END, @d);

  SELECT columns -- never use SELECT * in production code!
    FROM Honor.Scores
    WHERE ScoredAt >= @cutoff; -- now you have a chance to use an index
END
GO
```

Some further reading you may find useful:

- [Bad habits to kick : avoiding the schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix)
- [My stored procedure "best practices" checklist](https://sqlblog.org/2008/10/30/my-stored-procedure-best-practices-checklist)
- [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)
- [Bad habits to kick : using SELECT * / omitting the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)

Comment: Damn, you beat me to it, I was refactoring for MKII to use CASE and remove using variables on both sides of my statement to eliminate my table scans. Some of that pesky, paid work got in the way!

Answer (score 0):

Create three different procedures - GetMonthHighScores, GetWeekHighScores and GetDayHighScores.  Call the appropriate one for the given parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the most elegant and using functions in the WHERE clause like this is not a good idea Performance wise as you get Table Scans, but should get you started !  This will give the max score for the current Day, month or Year

```
CREATE PROC MaxScore ( @scope CHAR(1) )
AS

 SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF @scope = 'm'
        SELECT  MAX(value)
        FROM    scores
        WHERE   DATEPART(month, scoredat) = DATEPART(month, GETDATE())  
    IF @scope = 'd'
        SELECT  MAX(value)
        FROM    scores
        WHERE   DATEPART(day, scoredat) = DATEPART(day, GETDATE())
    IF @scope = 'y'
        SELECT  MAX(value)
        FROM    scores
        WHERE   DATEPART(year, scoredat) = DATEPART(year, GETDATE())
    ELSE
       RAISERROR('Invalid Input',0,1)
```

You could do it a number of ways, you may want to check out the following commands with your further requirements (availability depending upon your version)

```
CASE, EOMONTH, BEGIN TRY CATCH THROW
```

also look at ALL of the date functions & converting Date formats and have a play, it opens up a whole world to manipulate your queries

```
DATEADD, DATEPART, DATEDIFF, CONVERT
```

SQL Server Books Online has all of these parameters and offers the formatting codes for dates too so worth a bookmark